# Need to track total data transfer using Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, tcpip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software to report internet traffic for home user](https://superuser.com/questions/107879/software-to-report-internet-traffic-for-home-user)

I'm looking for a utility that can run in Win 7 and tell me how much data transfer my machine does per month. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You'll get a better answer to this on superuser.com - this should be automagically migrated there soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Networx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) will do the job.

Comment: I just love the tool..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the free version of Bandwidth Monitor 2 by Rakario Software

http://www.rokario.com/products/bandmon/2-0/

Answer (score 0):

If a sidebar gadget is appropriate for you, I personally use (http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=4f9274ce-427b-4063-868f-894079283b2c&bt=1&pl=1) this gadget to track monthly usage and to see instant transfer speeds. This is a very practical but not detailed solution.